# React: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, dom, redux, react-redux

I am using react in rails. But when I run the app, I get an error: Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

My index.jsx file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "../bundles/HelloWorld/reducers/index.js";
import App from "../bundles/HelloWorld/components/App"
let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also, I using this in application.html.erb like this:

What could be the error behind this?

Comment: Seems like your index.html might not have an element with id 'root'.

Comment: @anurag Then what should I do for that?

Comment: Insert a div with id `root` inside your body tag.
```<body>
<!-- ....any existing code -->
<div id="root"></div>
</body>```

Comment: @anurag not working with that.

Comment: @anurag I am using rails thats why I also have `<%= yield %>`

Comment: `Also, I using this in application.html.erb like this:` ---- Do add the code for application.html.erb, for clarity and for people falling into same troubles in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an element with `id='root`' to the page e.g.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
);
```

`render` expects a DOM element as the second argument, which doesn't exist in your case. You could either set it on the page itself or generate it dynamically as shown above.